# var express = require("express"); returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to node.js and pulling data dynamically through a server. I am attempting to connect to my DB and pull in comments that are stored there. I have tried several different answers (found on stackoverflow) to solve my problem, but none of them worked. For some reason var express = require("express"); returns undefined

**Server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = express();

var connection  =     mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "root",
    database : "moviewer"
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected with Database");
    }
});

app.use(express.session());

app.listen(8888,function() {
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 8888");
});

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/load',function(req,res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * from movie-reviews",function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
        } else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        }
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Moviewer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.2",
    "mysql": "~2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it installed actually?

Comment: What path does `require.resolve('express')` give you? Does that file resemble [the project's source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.12.2/index.js) (adjust the "tag" as needed)?

Comment: If express is not installed `require()` would throw an error… Is it?

Comment: what do you mean by `var express = require('express')` returns undefined?  Because, yes, the statement returns a value of undefined if you typed that into the Node console.  Did you do a console.log(express)?  There's a lot of things off with what you're asking.

Comment: I have installed express. I added my package.json for reference.

Comment: `var express = require(“express”);` is a assign operator and it always return undefined (void).

What and where you got  the `undefined` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem might be: **NODE_PATH environment variable** is not set for global/local module.

Based on your question I just executed small sample code and server is getting started using express.Code which I executed is as follows:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3700;
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.send("It works!");
});
app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

I believe, you should set **NODE_PATH** environment variable where your express module is available.It will work.